# Cannot read property 'something' of undefined react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

> Blockquote

hey everyone, i am new to react_hooks and i am trying to fetch an item in a component, but i am getting an error "Cannot read property 'something' of undefined", cuz the component is returning the jsx before dispatching the function getItem(id), and when i don't type anything in the return section i am getting the information of the item

```
import React, { Component,useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {getItem, addComment,addReply, addItem, deleteItem } from '../actions/itemActions';
import {addToCart} from '../actions/authActions';
import { CustomInput, Col, Row, Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import ReactTimeAgo from 'react-time-ago';
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';function Item(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    const [item, setItem] = useState({})
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getItem(id)).then(() => setItem(product))
    }, [id]);

    const img1 = "http://localhost:5000/"
    const product = useSelector(state => state.item.product)
    
     const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated)
    console.log(item)
  
return (
    <div>
    {isAuthenticated  ? (
    <ListGroupItem className="m-2">
                {item.images.length == 0 ? <img className="img_item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/FFFFFF/000000/?text=goshop.com" />:null}
                  {item.images.map((image) => (
                    <div>
                    <img className="img_item" src={img1,image} />
                    </div>
                  ))}<div> 
               <Link to={{
                pathname:`/item/${item._id}`,
                query:{item: item}
              }}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </div> 
                  <div>
                  <span className='text-danger mr-3'> Price: {item.price}$ </span> 
                  {item.price_sale ? <span className='last_price'> {item.price_sale}$ </span>:null }
                  </div>
                </ListGroupItem> 
      ):null} 
    </div>
  );
}export default Item;
```

Comment: Give item a default value in useState

Comment: thx a lot, i fixed the problem